# DateTimePicker Control Reporting Value is not a member of string

Tags: .net, string, vb.net, date, datetimepicker

I have two dateTimePicker controls on my form as follows:

```
Dim From As String = dateFrom.Value.Year.ToString + "-" + dateFrom.Value.Month.ToString + "-" + dateFrom.Value.Day.ToString
Dim dateTo As String = dateTo.Value.Year.ToString + "-" + dateTo.Value.Month.ToString + "-" + dateTo.Value.Day.ToString
```

So the first declaration is not showing any errors but the second declaration is returing an error: `Value is not a member of string`
Now i dont understand why since they are all `dataTimePickers`

Answer (score 3):

`Dim dateTo As String = dateTo.Value...etc`

It thinks they are the same variable, where the second `dateTo` should be your `DateTimePicker`

Just rename one of them.